# C#. Visual Studio 2015. Windows Forms. Почему при отладке не отображается новый textbox?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Используется: C#, Visual Studio 2015, Windows Forms.
На **Windows Forms** имеется много кнопок и **textbox**.
Добавил новый **textbox**.
Запускаю отладку(F5), а новый **textbox** на **Windows Forms** не отображается.

**ВОПРОС**
Почему при отладке на **Windows Forms** не отображается новый **textbox**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверьте:

1. Стоит ли в свойствах `visible` в `true`
2. Другой элемент не заграждает ли ваш `TextBox`